# Delete files with only 1 hardlink? (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, find

I have a large amount of hardlinks for my MythTV recordings into another directory organized specifically for Plex. As it is now, if I delete a recording in MythTV it would still have a hardlink in the Plex Directory. So as I understand it, the file isn't really deleted. I would like to add a line to my script that would delete files from the Plex directory if they no longer exist in MythTV recordings.

What I've come up with so far is running `find -links 1` on my Plex recordings directory should return all recordings deleted from MythTV (`find -links 2` lists every file currently)

how would I go about having it delete every file that's found with 
`find /media/NAS/PlexRecordings/ -links 1`?

Comment: You just add the `-exec` clause: `find /media/NAS/PlexRecordings/ -links 1 -exec rm {} \;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the `-delete` switch to the `find` command to delete the files it finds.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize there was a -delete option I'll have to test it out, but it sounds like a simplest solution.